# How to evaluate employees based on a variable data set?

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, dataset

I'm trying to find a way to evaluate a set of employees at my company. I've got reports that show sales figures, but one rep may be given jobs that are worth more that others are given, thus that employees sales will be higher. That's okay because much more work is involved in the higher dollar jobs, but I'm trying to find a way to compare employees based on these numbers and I'm having trouble finding common ground. Any ideas?

(fyi: in my attempts at solving this problem, I added a geometric mean to the right column, but that only tells me how likely that rep is to receive a high dollar job.)

Thanks, James[[image: Picture of my current data set]